# Как передать HTML файл на скачивания Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, веб-сервер

есть веб сервер `nginx`, там включен Directory Index Listing. Там лежат несколько файлов, включая `html` подскажите, можно ли на уровне конифгов, сделать так чтобы при переходе на `html` файл, он его не отображал, а скачивал ?

P.S.
языки программирования отсутвуют

Comment: попробуйте последний пример в https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types

Comment: @nörbörnën Помогло, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

В итоге конфиг файл выглядит у меня так

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location /nginx {
        types        { }  #Задаёт соответствие расширений имён файлов и MIME-типов ответов. Расширения нечувствительны к регистру символов. Одному MIME-типу может соответствовать несколько расширений
        default_type application/octet-stream; #Для того чтобы для определённого location’а для всех ответов выдавался MIME-тип
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        autoindex_localtime on; 
}


...
```